# How to delete specific element from an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can i delete a specified element from an array?

for example i added elements from an array like this:

> ```
>         int[] array = new int[5];
>         for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
>         {
>             array[i] = i;
>         }
> ```

How to delete the element from index 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the built in `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` class. If you want to delete elements don't make your life harder than it has to be.

```
list.RemoveAt(2);
```

Keep in mind the actual code to do this is not that complex. The thing is, why not take advantage of the built-in classes?

```
public void RemoveAt(int index)
{
    if (index >= this._size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    this._size--;
    if (index < this._size)
    {
        Array.Copy(this._items, index + 1, this._items, index, this._size - index);
    }
    this._items[this._size] = default(T);
    this._version++;
}
```